# In "Give it here!", is "here" a pronoun, adverb, preposition, or what?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, intransitive-preposition, locative

In the American regionalism,

> "Give it **here!**"

(i.e. Pass that thing my way -> in my direction -> Give it to me)

Questions:

1. What part of speech is the word "here"? That is, is it a pronoun, adverb, preposition, or what?
2. Is the word "here" occupying the *indirect object* slot of the ditransitive verb?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82324/discussion-on-question-by-tomauo-in-give-it-here-is-here-a-pronoun-adver).

Answer (score 7):

*Here* is a preposition. Notice that it takes the place of a preposition phrase, not a noun.

- Give it **to me**.
- Give it **here**.

*Here* is not an indirect object in the sentence. It is a locative complement.

[ Note: In the nineteenth century, many grammarians thought 'prepositions' were words that came before nouns. This started to change about ninety years ago. Most modern grammarians now understand 'prepositions' as a grammatical class of word. These words, like verbs for example, can sometimes occur before a noun, but sometimes before a verb, before preposition, before a clause - or before nothing at all! In the Original Poster's example we see the preposition *here* occurring with no object. There is no extra word after this preposition.

For an introduction to the grammar of prepositions see: *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* Huddleston & Pullum 2005 - or for a simpler introduction: [*Oxford Modern English Grammar* Aarts 2011](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Oxford-Modern-English-Grammar-Aarts/dp/0199533199/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1417266880&sr=8-1&keywords=oxford+modern+english+grammar) ]

Comment: In old-fashioned grammar-speak, what is "the object of the preposition 'here'"?

Comment: Even though _here_ can be substituted for a prepositional phrase, it is never a preposition itself. There is no object to the "preposition". It is clearly an adverb.

Comment: @TRomano: In old-fashioned grammar-speak, [*The object of a preposition is the noun or pronoun governed by a preposition.*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_of_a_preposition.htm) Given the only two words in Araucaria's second example are the verb ***give*** and the pronoun ***it***, it should be pretty obvious which one it is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  "It" is the direct object of the verb "give". The recipient in #1 is "me" (to me) and the recipient in #2 is represented (or supplanted) by "here". If "here" is a preposition, what (pro)noun does it govern? "it" ain't it.

Comment: @TRomano: I don't really understand what you're trying to establish. In *my* ideolect, the preposition ***to*** in Araucaria's first example is optional, given that particular word-order. But to speakers of more restrictive dialects, it *must* be present to indicate the relationship of the indirect object ***me*** to the main activity (verb + direct object ***give it***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My question is, since we find "here" instead of "(to) me" in "Give it *here*", what would modern linguists call *here* there?

Comment: @TRomano: I think 200_success has already answered that specific point. The fact that you can replace ***to me*** with ***here*** doesn't imply "syntactic equivalence". I think it's probably fair to say ***here*** is an "adverb" which can often be used *without any preposition at all* (consider *"This goes [to] here"*, when explaining how some parts fit together). It's not a preposition *in itself*, but it sometimes acts as if it *contains* one - in addition to having its primary *semantic* content.

Comment: @TRomano In post-Jespersen grammar, it's an **intransitive preposition**.  It has no object.  In ye olden days, people'd call it an **adverb** instead because of an arbitrary requirement that prepositions be transitive, which unfortunately makes a bit of a theoretical mess.  (Imagine if we called intransitive verbs "adverbs" despite their lack of similarity to other adverbs!)

Comment: +1, but now you've done it! :D . . . This thread might end up getting migrated to ELU, where it can get answered by those high-rep-SWR-users who can't identify a grammatical subject.

Comment: Actually, your answer post is very short, and perhaps more suited to be a comment because it does not answer the OP's question of whether the *adverb 'here'* occupies the indirect object slot. :D . . . Okay, okay, I'll go get me some coffee real soon.

Comment: @snailboat: thank you for the post-Jespersen terminology. I will read up on intransitive prepositions. It's puzzling to me that they decided to keep the name 'preposition' when these words can be in front of nothing.

Comment: @TRomano That's a good point.  But keep in mind that *adverb* is often used for words that don't modify verbs (as in *very quickly*, where *very* modifies another adverb), despite its etymology.  *Preposition* can be treated the same way.

Comment: @200_success The arbitrary idea that a word  can be classed according to the word that it precedes has been shown to be unprincipled and unsupportable. (Imagine trying to classify nouns or verbs this way.) Instead modern grammarians have decided to class this group of word on the basis that the members share various synactic properties. This means that we now have a grown-up account of the category preposition. It does however mean that the title 'preposition' isn't a good one, but the feeling is it is too established to change it ... Other labels are equally as bad, e.g. "adverb" ...

Comment: The "Traditionally not a pronoun" examples on p. 128 make a compelling case. If you could edit your answer to include a clarification and citation of this modern definition of prepositions, then I would be able to retract my downvote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I highly recommend the section on prepositions in the Huddleston and Pullum book in the link in the comment above. It's very interesting and even if you end up disagreeing with it first time round, you'll have a clear picture where other folks are coming from on this! :)

Comment: @Araucaria: IMO, The greater stumbling block to understanding this modern approach is that the preposition can exist alone, i.e. not governing a noun; "intransitive prepositions" seems like an oxymoron.  I would understand "with" in the question "Are you coming with?" (are you going to accompany us? are you coming along?) as a particle that belongs with the verb 'come'.

Comment: @TRomano Yes, quite. Just difficult to change such an established term. The other argument for not changing the word used, is that other word category titles are also bad ... I would change the name to *relators* if I had my way! Or maybe *Orientives* :)

Comment: I've retracted my vote, but I think the answer is too biased in insisting that the traditional definition has been obsolete for nearly a whole century and that modern definition is universally accepted. The [top](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/preposition) [three](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/prepositions.htm) [hits](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preposition) on Google for "define preposition" all say that prepositions are to be used with a noun-like complement.

Comment: I like the fourth hit, though, which uses the term [prepositional adverb](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Prepositional-Adverb.htm). It recognizes the modern view without revising entrenched terminology.

Comment: I hope no one ever uses the term "prepositional adverb" on this site.

Comment: @Araucaria So, what about the OP's second question? :D . . . (Aside: You know, there's another passive question that's come up which might interest you, something about a passive using "GO". Actually, there've been a few number of passive related questions.)

Comment: Let's see, I'm guessing that "prepositional adverb" might be paralleling current existing stuff like "noun clause", "adjective clause", "noun-y", etc. :D

Answer (score 1):

I would say in the idiomatic expression "Give it here" "here" in 
connection with "give" is element of a compound verb. Traditional grammar would call it adverbial particle, I often say compound particle/element.

I can't imagine that all speakers use this expression as it has a strong similarity to German Gib's her meaning Give it to me. This use of here as compound element is slightly different from its use as adverb of place. German differentiates and has two words: her and hier.

In traditional grammar "here" is an adverb of place. It is no prepositon as it is not connected with a noun. And it is no pronoun, it does not stand for a noun.

Answer (score 0):

1. What part of speech is the word "here"? That is, is it a pronoun, adverb, preposition, or what?

I'll pass, thanks.

2. Is the word "here" occupying the indirect object slot of the ditransitive verb?

No.  No matter whether we call it an adverb or an intransitive preposition, it still fits the same kind of slot that an adverb or a preposition can fill in this sentence.  It's an adjunct, not an argument.  It's not filling the same slot as the "me" in "Give me it."